# Is it possible to use a Material Color Palette in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-ui

The Material.io Website provides a convenient color generator which I used to generate the following color theme: https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=F4511E&secondary.color=F57F17

Using the export function of the color generator you can download the corresponding xml color file for Android. I tried to build and/or modified an existing Material theme in Android studio but it seems that the SDK (V.22) I am using is unable to recognize most of the color attributes.

Question: What would be a working method of using or importing the values of this file into Android studio so that it can be used in themes with the effect of the preview in the Material.io Website:

```
    <resources>
    <color name="primaryColor">#ffccbc</color>
    <color name="primaryLightColor">#ffffee</color>
    <color name="primaryDarkColor">#cb9b8c</color>
    <color name="secondaryColor">#ffab91</color>
    <color name="secondaryLightColor">#ffddc1</color>
    <color name="secondaryDarkColor">#c97b63</color>
    <color name="primaryTextColor">#795548</color>
    <color name="secondaryTextColor">#5d4037</color>
    </resources>
```

I have been reading any google developer spec I could find including those most recent here without being able to get them working in a theme:

https://developer.android.com/design/ and here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Styles

Comment: Can't understand what exactly you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Set colors to your AppTheme in `style.xml` then they will be used for the view in your application. I hope I understood your question correctly.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="primaryColor">#ffccbc</item>
    <item name="primaryLightColor">#ffffee</item>
    <item name="primaryDarkColor">#cb9b8c</item>
    <item name="secondaryColor">#ffab91</item>
    <item name="secondaryLightColor">#ffddc1</item>
    <item name="secondaryDarkColor">#c97b63</item>
    <item name="primaryTextColor">#795548</item>
    <item name="secondaryTextColor">#5d4037</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer I tried that and declaring those in a theme will only affect the primaryColor and secondaryColor but not much more as it seems you also need the corresponding Material base classes not present in the regular SDK environment. I am just installing the Material Plugin which I believe will remediate that problem.

Comment: If I declare them in a style the build fails with : error: style attribute 'attr/primaryColor not found.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a feature which will be available in Android P. I found the following documentation explaining how to install the components in Android Studio providing the needed extensions to be able to work with the material design UI:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Using the downloaded color definitions runs into an error because prior to Android P and api level 28 there are no components available using them.